# Find the value of $\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, definite-integrals, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $f(x)$ be continous on $[0; 1]$, satisfy the following condition:
>
> 1. $$f(1) = 0$$
> 2. $$\int_0^1 [f'(x)]^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = 7$$
> 3. $$\int_0^{1} x^2f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{1}{3}$$
>    Find the value of $\int_0^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$

I have tried but the problem is I was unable to get anything from $(2)$. From $(3)$, using integration by parts, I get this:

$$\int_0^{1} (x^3f(x))' \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$$

But this isn't any help at all. Any idea for this problem?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3552264/find-function-fx-that-is-continuous-on-0-2-satisfies-f2-3-int-0?rq=1  use same technicque as here ,cauchy helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3552264/find-function-fx-that-is-continuous-on-0-2-satisfies-f2-3-int-0?rq=1)  by user :[Fred](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/380717/fred)

By  IBP $$\int_0^1 x^3 f'(x)=0-\int_0^1 3x^2 f(x)$$ So $$\int_0^1 x^3 f'(x)=-1$$ Now by cauchy schwarz $$1={\left(\int_0^1 x^3 f'(x)\right)}^2\le \int_0^1 x^6\int_0^1 f'(x)^2=\frac{1}{7} \cdot 7$$ That means for equality of C-S must occur ie $f'(x)=\eta x^3\implies f(x)=\frac{\eta}{4} x^4 + C$

Now to find $\eta$  substitute it into $\int_0^1 x^2 f(x)=1/3$ after which you can easily find $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$

Comment: Ah, after reading your answer, I now understand my mistakes while reading your linked question. Thanks!